What do we do with an abandoned challenge that requires the author's participation?
When the author of a challenge makes a commitment to a challenge posted (e.g. "The timing will be done on my machine") but then clearly gives up on the challenge (e.g. by attempting to destroy it through vandalism), we surely can't expect them to live up to their commitment. That leaves us with dysfunctional challenge. What do we do then?
Case in point: Sum of Positive and Negative Powers of 2

Nothing
Challenges of this type are usually only maintained for a short time. Authors stop scoring new submissions after a while, new submissions can still be posted but they can't be officially scored. Sometimes challengers attempt to estimate their own score. There are many king-of-the-hill and fastest-code challenges that are in this state and they are not really considered a problem.
Since we leave those alone we should leave this one alone too, the only difference is it was abandoned a bit faster.
